# Which is faster: define an empty var or check if it is empty

Tags: php, performance

Sorry if this sounds dumb or have been asked previously; it's not exactly about performance, more about "how does it work under the hood". 
So, what would be (if any) speed difference between:

```
if(!empty($a)) { $a = 'whatever';}
```

and

```
$a = ''; $a = 'whatever';
```

...where 'whatever' is not always a string, but anything, incl. function value return.
It's like very basic things have escaped me (or it's just a lack of sleep);  please, feel free to crucify me and thank you in advance for replies.

Comment: If you're talking about speed-difference, you're essentially talking about performance. The latter would *always* assign the value, while the first would only assign it if the variable is not already empty, so they are logically different too.

Comment: @Qirel thank you for note; yet, skipping differences, which is faster?

Comment: Honestly, there's very little that is different with them in terms of speed - the second one would be `$a = 'whatever';` anyways, so the first assignment to empty is pointless. Like I said, they're logically different and do different things in the end, so you can't really compare them, it's like comparing apples to bananas. If you want to optimize your code, this isn't what you should be doing - optimize something that matters instead ;-)

Comment: excuse me , but what's the logic behind your first statement ?

Comment: and the more performance the more speed.

Comment: @Qirel sorry, seems I'm not quite good in a questions asking, let me , please, try again. So, it is a lot of code and somewhere between the lines I've been doing ** if(!empty($a) { // do stuff... ** to prevent "undefined value" notices.  Essentially, the result of ** $a = ''; $a = 'whatever' **  is the same (so first assignment is not exactly pointless here, it prevents php from throwing notices). So, have just thought, if one can substitutes   another, any reason to continue using IF statement? Guess the question     is totally pointless, yet just out of curiosity.

Comment: @hassan Have just added a comment, which extends my question, thank you for your note.

Comment: If the question is about preventing undefined variables, there's a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef which should answer that.

Comment: @Qirel not exactly, yet thank you for pointing; you're probably right, should do more reading first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did my homework (thanks Google and https://3v4l.org/) and here's the results (screen grabs speak for themselves):

**Create an empty var first**
[image]

Check it with IF 
[image]

Thanks to all who has participated!